# Best practise for PostgreSQL backup

Tags: backup, postgresql

I'm writing a script for backing up PostgreSQL each night and I'm happy with doing a full database dump. I'm curious about how I should backing up though. Is it wise for me to first do a VACUUM and then a full dump? Does this reduce the size of the backed up file? (I will be compressing the file into a tar so I don't know if it even matters)

Since the script will be backing up nightly, is there something like too much VACUUMing? Or should I leave VACUUM to another script that runs say once a month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VACUUM` only affects the size of physical backups (`pg_basebackup`, etc), not logical backups (dumps). You don't need to.

There's no such thing as too much `VACUUM`. It's harmless. You shouldn't need manual `VACUUM` though, just make sure autovacuum is enabled and set to run enough.

I strongly advise that you use point-in-time recovery as well as logical backups though. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html). There are helper tools like [pgbarman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) and WAL-E for this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! After your advice,I did follow up reading deeper and I'll have to rethink how I'm backing up. Maybe do both physical and logical backups and set autovacuum